# A question on the property of injective function

Tags: calculus

In my finance class my prof said that since the exponential function is injective it follows that
$\exp(a(t))=\exp(b(t))\exp(c(t))$ for all $t$ implies  $a=b+c$ where $a,b,c $ are functions of $t$.
Can somebody explain why this holds for all injective functions ?

Comment: This should be $a=b+c$. An injective function is one that has the property that if $f(x) = f(y)$ then $x=y$.

Comment: Do you know what the definition of an injective function mean? and plus this only holds for a special case of injective functions.

Comment: You need the function to be a *homomorphism* as well, ie $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ for all $a,b$.

Comment: @Chinny84 yes I do know the definition of injectivity

Comment: @JohnDouma thanks I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$$
e^a = e^b e^c,
$$
then
$$
e^{a-b-c}=1=e^0.
$$
Hence $a-b-c=0$, or $a=b+c$ by injectivity of the exponential function.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be an injective homomorphism. If $f(a(t))=f(b(t))f(c(t))$ for every value of $t$, then $f(a(t))=f(b(t)c(t))$ by the homomorphism property (the exponential function satisfies this).

As $f$ is injective, this means $a(t)=b(t)c(t)$ for every value of $t$ since otherwise they would disagree at a particular point.

As this holds for all $t$, we just write $a=bc$ to say that they are equal as *functions* and not just at a particular value of $t$.

**EDIT:** I should mention that although the exponential function is a homomorphism is some sense, it is not directly as defined above. However exp satisfies $exp(a+b)=exp(a)exp(b)$ which is good enough for our purposes.

Comment: How is a homomorphism defined in this case?

Comment: A (group) homomorphism is a function $f$ that satisifies $f(a*b)=f(a) \circ f(b)$ where $*$ and $\circ$ are the respective (group) operations. In this case, $*$ is addition and $\circ$ is multiplication so we have $f(a+b)=f(a) \times f(b)$ which is the form that $exp$ satisfies.